# Ifstream read fails at a specific size (unrelated to file size)

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to read a file and I realized that it would fail because I would be trying to read too much data, even though the file is much bigger than what I'm trying to read.

The file is 120 MB, and my ifstream fails at 12967 bytes (even though it starts acting weird at 12801.

Here is code illustrating my problem:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;

#define CORRECT_SIZE 12800
#define CORRECT_BUT_WIERD 12966
#define INCORRECT_SIZE 12967

bool check_error_bits(ifstream* f);

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("myfile.txt");
    char c[CORRECT_SIZE];
    char c2[CORRECT_BUT_WIERD];
    char c3[INCORRECT_SIZE];

    /*
     * TEST A (works fine)
    */
    myFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    myFile.read(c, CORRECT_SIZE);
    check_error_bits(&myFile);
    cout << myFile.tellg() << std::endl; // Here, tellg() returns 12800

    /*
     * TEST B (works too, but acts wierd)
     */
    myFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    myFile.read(c2, CORRECT_BUT_WIERD);
    check_error_bits(&myFile);
    cout << myFile.tellg() << std::endl; // Here, tellg() returns 16896

    /*
     * TEST C (FAIL)
    */
    myFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    myFile.read(c3, INCORRECT_SIZE);
    check_error_bits(&myFile);
    cout << myFile.tellg() << std::endl; // Here, tellg() returns -1

    system("pause");
}

bool check_error_bits(ifstream* f)
{
    bool stop = false;

    if (f->eof())
    {
        char msg[500];
        strerror_s(msg, errno);
        cout << "1: " << msg << std::endl;
    }

    if (f->fail())
    {
        char msg[500];
        strerror_s(msg, errno);
        cout << "2: " << msg << std::endl;
        stop = true;
    }

    if (f->bad())
    {
        char msg[500];
        strerror_s(msg, errno);
        cout << "3: " << msg << std::endl;
        stop = true;
    }

    return stop;
}
```

Trying to read less than 12800 bytes works perfectly well. From 128001 to 12966, it works (although I have not checked if the data is correct), but tellg() returns non-sense. After 12966, read simply fails.

The console output of that program is:

```
12800
16896
1: No error
2: No error
-1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I assume you're using VC++ as your compiler, from the <Windows.h> include. Are you compiling as 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: 32 bit, I didn't think it would matter with such low numbers?

Comment: Probably not, but it fell under the category of "nice to know"

Comment: @MyUsername112358 What exactly did you actually observe when debugging? You did I'd suppose.

Comment: hints: add "ios::binary" in myFile constructor; dump bytes 16895-16897 of file; close and open file between each test.

Comment: It worked, but I don't understand why? Isn't 1 byte in binary the same as 1 byte in text mode?

Comment: Let me bet: character 16896 has value "26=0x1a"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Windows environment and text files, a character with value 26=0x1A=^Z is taken as "end fo file".

For this reason, if file is not open as binary, an unexpected eof can be received even when file is bigger.

See wikipedia "End of file" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file):

*In Microsoft's DOS and Windows (and in CP/M and many DEC operating systems), reading from the terminal will never produce an EOF. Instead, programs recognize that the source is a terminal (or other "character device") and interpret a given reserved character or sequence as an end-of-file indicator; most commonly this is an ASCII Control-Z, code 26.*

Answer (score 2):

You have a 16,896 byte file. The first read works fine. The second read encounters an end of file and can only read 16,896 bytes. Your third read fails because you didn't clear the end of file flag on your stream.

You may also have a 120MB file, but that's not relevant. Check the size of the file in code. (Or it may be 120MB of binary data but you're reading it in text mode.)

Comment: The file is 120 MB... It's way bigger than 16896 bytes.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 How did you determine that? Be as precise as you can.

Comment: myFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
 cout << "File size: " << myFile.tellg() << std::endl; // returns 123153562

Comment: Reading in binary makes it works, but why? Wouldn't 1 byte in text mode be the same as 1 byte in binary?

Comment: Read a file in ascii mode means read the data and return whatever the operating system decides.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> (although I have not checked if the data is correct)

Do this, because i think the data is correct.

I assume that you're using windows, so:
[Why can't Explorer decide what size a file is?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/15/10140985.aspx)

also https://superuser.com/questions/567175/why-is-the-folder-size-in-properties-different-from-the-total-file-folder-size

Comment: I'm aware that WIndows doesn't show the filesize accurately, but I made this file myself and it's way bigger than 16,896 bytes. (It's avout 120 MB)